# vba WinHttp.WinHttpRequest метод POST. не получается отправить переменную в форму

Tags: vba, winhttp

Есть [страничка](http://kodifikant.ru/phones/) с телефонными кодами городов:

На ней есть форма для поиска кода по названию города:

```
<form method="get" action="/phones/ru/search">    <label for="city">Узнать код по городу:</label>    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" style="width: 120px;"/>    <label for="phonenumber">или номеру телефона:</label>    <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" style="width: 120px;" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-____" value=""/>    <input type="submit" value="Найти" class="btn" style="width: 80px;"/>    <input type="hidden" name="part" value="ru"/>  </form>
```

При "ручном управлении" ну то-есть с сайта, в поле "city" вводится название города, нажимается кнопка "найти" и получаем страничку с кодом этого города. 
Я попытался получить содержимое страницы с кодом этого конкретного города нижеприведенным способом, но в результате получил страницу равнозначную странице ошибки при поиске.

```
Dim http As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim txt As String
Dim timeout As Integer
Dim request As String

timeout = 5000
http.SetTimeouts timeout, timeout, timeout, timeout

request = "{ ""city"": """ & "Москва" & """ }" 'Ну это скорее всего от безнадеги чисто попытался.

http.Open "POST", "http://kodifikant.ru/phones/", False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

http.send request

WriteToFile "C:\temp\phonecode.html", http.ResponseText
```

Собственно просьба:

> Подскажите плз, что у меня не правильно.

Comment: Ecли написано  `form method="get"` это означает что нужно делать `get` запрос, а не `post`. Сделайте запрос в браузере, и тупо перепишите строку адреса себе, и по ней сделайте GET запрос. А если вам не понятно уже как сделать GET запрос - переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Ну да, тупанул... ((( Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim http As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim txt As String
Dim timeout As Integer
Dim request As String
Dim encodedCity as String

timeout = 5000
http.SetTimeouts timeout, timeout, timeout, timeout

'Надо подключить функцию для енкодинда строки с названием города
'encodedCity = URLEncode("Москва") 
encodedCity = "%CC%EE%F1%EA%E2%E0"

request = "city=" & encodedCity &"phonenumber=&part=ru" 

http.Open "GET", "http://kodifikant.ru/phones/ru/search", False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

http.send request

'Если город найден, сайт возвращает код 302 и сразу редиректит на страницу 
'города. Иначе открывает список городов.

If http.status = "302" Then

   WriteToFile "C:\temp\phonecode.html", http.ResponseText

End If
```

Вам нужно объявить в вашем коде еще одну функцию для енкодинга названия города.
URLEncode, можно взять любую из этих, к сожалению небыло возможности проверить какая из них рабочая.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba